# Wordpress: Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, internal

I must move my wordpress website from one server to another. There is no way to backup it, so I copied wp-content files and moved to the new server. Also I moved database, so in my new server I have same database, same user, same password, also I changes user and password info in wp-config.php file.

But there is a problem such:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the
>   error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

and here is error log:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-06-24 22:07:41
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
2015-06-24 22:07:40 W3SVC181 P3NWVPWEB067 50.62.160.227 GET /admin.php - 80 - 193.201.227.78 HTTP/1.0 Opera/9.80+(Windows+NT+6.1;+U;+ru)+Presto/2.8.131+Version/11.10 - - voskevaz.info 404 0 2 1333 179 4843
2015-06-24 22:07:40 W3SVC181 P3NWVPWEB067 50.62.160.227 GET /administrator/index.php - 80 - 193.201.227.78 HTTP/1.0 Opera/9.80+(Windows+NT+6.1;+U;+ru)+Presto/2.8.131+Version/11.10 - - voskevaz.info 404 0 2 1333 193 203
2015-06-24 22:07:43 W3SVC181 P3NWVPWEB067 50.62.160.227 GET /wp-login.php - 80 - 193.201.227.78 HTTP/1.0 Opera/9.80+(Windows+NT+6.1;+U;+ru)+Presto/2.8.131+Version/11.10 - - voskevaz.info 302 0 0 564 182 1250
```

I really don't know what does it mean and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Try:
- switching to the Twenty Eleven theme by renaming your current theme's folder in wp-content/themes and adding "-old" to the end of the folder name using FTP or whatever file management application your host provides.

- resetting the plugins folder by FTP or phpMyAdmin.

- re-uploading all files & folders - except the wp-content folder - from a fresh download of WordPress.

Comment: That's an *error log*?? It looks more like an access log to me. Also, it doesn't contain any `5xx` response codes, so the error you mentioned has been logged somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of a `5xx` response code in your log file is interesting.

In the log extract you posted above, the last line is a request for `/wp-admin.php`, and is served with a `302` response code, which means it was redirected somewhere else.

I'm guessing this is happening because you configured the site to only allow users to log in over a secure (HTTPS) connection. So when you visit `http://··(your site)··/wp-login.php`, you're being redirected to `https://··(your site)··/wp-login.php`. If the new site doesn't have a proper SSL certificate installed, this will cause an error. (And it looks like your site is logging HTTPS traffic somewhere else.)

To prevent this from happening, edit `/wp-config.php` and change `define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);` to `define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', false);`.